# What does it mean by late boil?

Tags: first-time-brewer

I am looking at a Christmas ale to brew and found this recipe (I am still learning to brew, so I am using malt extracts)
https://www.brewtoad.com/recipes/variant-of-great-lakes-christmas-ale-clone
. I am guessing 5 gallons of water and steep the grains for 20 minutes?

Comment: There is also this post that answers your question: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12096/why-add-extract-late

Answer (score 1):

Late boil = The last few minutes of a boil. Usually for pastuerizing purposes of the addition. Typically 3-10 minutes.